# how to auto center thumbnails for all screen sizes

Tags: html, css, thumbnails, center, fluid-layout

```
body{
    width:auto;
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;
    width:100%;
    max-width:1980px;
    min-width:334px;    
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

This is my code. I need thumbnails to be in the center for all screen resolutions. But I can't do it. I even tried  tag. It didn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: what is your browser? if ie you must add `DOCTYPE`

Comment: You should show your relevant `html`, for a start; and ideally show a live demo for us to work with, on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or similar, that clearly demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this url : http://jsfiddle.net/DyRS4/2/

html:

```
<div id="my-div">my div</div>
```

css:

```
div#my-div{
    margin:0px auto;
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: that works for a certain screen size, but I asked something for all screen sizes, if it's possible. I want thumbs all floated and still in the center.

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.picture_area { width:/*width of picture area you want in pixels*/;
                height: auto; 
                min-width:/*smallest size of window in pixels that does not push pics left*/;}
                margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.navigation_area { margin-bottom: 5%; }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="navigation_area">
        <!--Nav code here-->
    </div>


    <div class="picture_area">
          <!--All your image code here-->
    </div>
```

You would want to create a special div for the area where you put your thumbnails in. First
you need to set the bottoms margins of your nav panel so they don't overlap with your pictures. Then define the width of your thumbnail area with pixels. For example `width: 500px; then set the min-width attribute to the smallest size that does not push pictures left. For example min-width: 500px;. Then to center it in the page set margin-left and margin-right for picture area to auto.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following components:

- height:100% for the html tag, body tag, container and an empty placeholder element
- display:inline-block; and vertical-align: middle for the content and placeholder to vertically center content that has an undefined height across browsers.
- the placeholder element is given 100% height to prop up the line box, so that vertical-align: middle has the desired effect.
- a fixed width container to wrap the images.
- display:inline for the content div and text-align center to the container div to do horizontal centering for content that has an undefined width across browsers.

Combine both the vertical-align and text-align techniques to create a centered image gallery:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Centered Image Gallery</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body, .container, .placeholder { height: 100%;}
    
    img { width:16px; height:16px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px; }
    
    .container { text-align:center; }
    
    /* Use width of less than 100% for Firefox and Webkit */
    .wrapper { width: 50%; }
    
    .placeholder, .wrapper, .content { vertical-align: middle; }
    
    /* Use inline-block for wrapper and placeholder */
    .placeholder, .wrapper { display: inline-block; }
    
    .fixed { min-width: 1px; }
    
    .content { display:inline; }
    
    @media,
     {
     .wrapper { display:inline; }
     }
     </style>
    
    </head>
      <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="fixed">
                <img src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://mozdev.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://webkit.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="https://vivaldi.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.srware.net/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://build.chromium.org/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://www.apple.com/favicon.ico">
                <img src="http://opera.com/favicon.ico">
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <span class="placeholder"></span>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```