# Centering full window video

Tags: css, html, video, html5-video, media-queries

I am trying to get a HTML5 video to act exactly like a `background: center center fixed; background-size: cover;` element without using JS (I know there are JS libraries that do that out there). I figured out how to set the width or height to 100% depending on the aspect ratio of the window compared to the aspect ratio of the video, using media queries (the example below assumes you're using a 16/9 video). All I have left to do now is get the video to center either horizontally or vertically.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  div#fixed video {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  div#fixed video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the [centered image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066145/how-to-auto-center-thumbnails-for-all-screen-sizes/11146227#11146227) gallery technique applied to a single video tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  div#fixed video {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin:auto 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  div#fixed video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    text-align: left;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need media queries to achieve that :)

Try this:

```css
#fixed {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 0;
}
#fixed video {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
 <video autoplay loop class="bg-video">
  <source src="https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/preview/abstract-rainbow_wjpctkdes__PM.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</div>
```

Here's a [working fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2jyLnm3L/).

Hope it helps :)